# How to return value from python from looped generation/function at def Python?

Tags: python-3.x, function, loops, return-value

Examble of my code.

```
from itertools import *
from collections import Counter
def combinations():
    for i in combinations_with_replacement(['a','b','c'], 3):
    #for i in permutations(['0','1','2'], 3):
        return (''.join(i))
def combinations2():
    for i in combinations_with_replacement(['1','2','3'], 3):
    #for i in permutations(['0','1','2'], 3):
        return (''.join(i))

print (combinations() + combinations2())
```

but it return only once, as example - aaa111 and stop .

i was try use yield , but it give me error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'generator' and 'generator'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get an error is because `yield` does not do the calculations. Instead it gives you a generator object which can generate values on the fly without storing them. Therefore, you will have to loop through the generator object getting the values and adding them.  Here's a [tutorial](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/)

```
from itertools import *
from collections import Counter
def combinations():
    for i in combinations_with_replacement(['a','b','c'], 3):
    #for i in permutations(['0','1','2'], 3):
        yield (''.join(i))
def combinations2():
    for i in combinations_with_replacement(['1','2','3'], 3):
    #for i in permutations(['0','1','2'], 3):
        yield (''.join(i))

for c in combinations():
    for c1 in combinations2():
        print(c+c1)
```

Answer (score 0):

with return too works at fly, if do like this

```
from itertools import *
from collections import Counter
def combinations():
    return (''.join(i) for i in combinations_with_replacement(['a','b','c'], 3))

def combinations2():
    return (''.join(i) for i in combinations_with_replacement(['1','2','3'], 3))


for c in combinations():
    for c1 in combinations2():
        print(c+c1)
```